# Изменений стиля при переходе на компонент

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Имеется контроллер на `/`

```
<template>
      <div id="app">
        <header id="header" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar fixed-top">
        </header>
        <router-view/>
      </div>
</template>

<style>
  header {
    background-color: #2159F6;
  }
</style>
```

*Как видно у контроллера, есть стили для тэга* `header`

Так же существует другой, контроллер `/anotherPage`

```
<template>
  <h1>Another Page </h1>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

И задача состоит в том чтобы поменять стиль `header` во 2 контроллере.

Пробовал так:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'anotherPage',
    data() {
      return {
        pageName: "anotherPage"
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.customStyle()
    },
    methods: {
      customStyle(){
        document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "#3996f5";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Но при использовании данного метода, есть недостаток, который выражается исключением с ошибкой: *Не найден `id` `#header`*. Исключение выбрасывает, если только сразу открыть страницу на 2 контроллере (`localhost/#/anotherPage`).

Answer (score 1):

Данную проблему возможно решить простой проверкой на существование, т.е.

```
if (document.getElementById("header")) 
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "#3996f5";
```

Но стандартно, такая проблема решается с помощью атрибута [scoped](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html), который применяется к тегу `style`. При этом, в однофайловом компоненте классы становятся "в локальной зоне видимости", т.е. применяются только к данному компоненту.

Пример:

```
<template> 
   <div class="item"> </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .item {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Это не работает. Я так понимаю он не видит header (2 контроллер)

Comment: Должен видеть. Область видимости для этого все приложение. Повесь не на хук `created`, а на `mounted`, похоже, дело в этом. Или, может быть, нужно уже в хуке `mounted`  использовать $nextTick, который вызывает callback после отрисовки изменений.